# Points of intersection of diagonals in $n$-sided polygon

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a convex polygon with $n$ sides and suppose that there are not two of its diagonals that are parallel nor three that concur in the same point that is not a vertex.

a) How many points of intersection do these diagonals have?

b) How many of these intersection points are interior to the polygon?

c) How many are exterior?

**Attempt:**

Since the number of diagonals is given by $\displaystyle \frac{n(n-3)}{2}=d$, we will have that, to form a point of intersection between diagonals, we will need $\displaystyle \binom{d}{2}$ .

However, from all this, we will have undue counts. For example: suppose we had a polygon of vertices $\displaystyle A_1,A_2,A_3,...,A_n$. We will have diagonals connected to the same vertex.
$$\displaystyle \binom{d}{2}-\left[\binom{n-3}{2}-1\right]$$

This is for letter a)... however, I didn't understand anything about the statement b) and c). What did I just do not count the intersections inside the polygon?

Comment: Hint: If the pairs of diagonals are formed from 4 distinct vertices, how many points of intersection do they yield? What If the pairs are formed from 3 distinct vertices? Hence, what's the total?  $\quad$ The intersections that you found could have existed inside, outside, or on the polygon. EG Consider a hexagon, to get intersections outside the polygon.

Comment: @CalvinLin Considering four vertices is enough to form two diagonals that intersect, but what guarantees that these points will not try to connect with their neighbors? Are we just considering the possibility that they won't try to connect with their neighbors?

Comment: The fact that the author is distinguishing between points of intersection and points of intersection interior to the polygon suggests that the author is thinking of the diagonals as lines rather than line segments.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig This seems to make sense. But I find it a bit ambiguous the fact that I didn't put this information

Comment: @Octupos What do you mean by "connect with their neighbors"? And why would they do that? (It's not clear to me what you're asking here / what your confusion is. Note that "no three diagonals concur at the same point that is not a vertex")    $\quad$ And yes, I'm going with the assumption that NF pointed out, for the reasons that they did. If you want to focus on line segments, the above hints still work (and just need to focus on line segments).

Comment: @CalvinLin Does a vertex not have the possibility to connect to an adjacent vertex? So in counting diagonals we do $n-3$

Comment: Yes vertices cannot connect to their neighboring vertices since it doesn't form a diagonal. And that affects the points of intersections that they yield. IE If the vertices are $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$, then you only have 1 intersection from $v_1 v_3 \cap v_2v_4$. Whereas if the vertices are $v_a, v_b, v_c, v_d$ where $a, b, c, d$ are spaced sufficiently far apart, then we have 3 points of intersection. $\quad$   In fact, one simplification of the solution could be to allow for $v_i v_{i+1}$ to be "diagonals", and then account for the "incorrect" points of intersection that they introduce.

Comment: @CalvinLin Excellent. thanks for clarifying me